# how to apply a VBA to multiple rows in MS excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very novice at this, I need to apply the below to rows with VBA, can anyone advise please.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A59")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B59:E59").ClearContents

    End If

     If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B59")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C59:E59").ClearContents

    End If

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C59")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("D59:E59").ClearContents

    End If

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D59")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("E59").ClearContents

    End If

End With
```

I have five dependent dropdown list columns each one is dependent of the previous.  I am trying to reset the cells once the previous column selection is changed. The above works fine but I do not know how to apply it to all rows or up to 10000 rows for example.

I would very much appreciate the guidance on this

Many thanks
G

Comment: Hm... use loop depending on your preferences.

Comment: Don't know how to add a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        If .Row >= 59 And .Row <= 10000 _
            And .Column <= 4 Then
            Range(Cells(.Row, .Column + 1), Cells(.Row, 5)).ClearContents
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a loop, you can try something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

  If Target.Row = 59 then
    If not IsEmpty(Target) then
      Range(Cells(59,Target.Column +1),Cells(59,"E")).ClearContents
    End If  
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, but this still wont solve the rows and will also delete any text in after column E.  A loop formula would be great.  Many thanks G

Comment: I didn't understand your problem. Can you provide a data example that this algorithm don't fit.